# Load an ExtJS form

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs3

**I have a Simple Extjs form1 with several textfields and a button.**

**When i click on the button on form1,a form2 is Popped open.**

The problem i am facing is, ***i cannot get the values from the form2 into form1***, unless form2 is instantiated.

**Is there anyway i can load/instantiate the form2 before form1 so that i can get the values from the form2,using Ext.getcmp('id') into form1?**

Being a novice in Extjs, i hope my question is Not vague.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. If you want, populate the form field values ( I mean Form1 fields ) by Form2, this is so simple. Drop me message if you want this.

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir Thanks for your reply. Actually, Based on the inputs in form1, i want to disable a text-field in form 2. Since form2 is loaded after form1 does, Ext.cmp('id') give a null value. Can you help?

Comment: Dear friend, lets do on `jsfiddle`. Put your codes in there and share link with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the inputs from form 1 into form 2 as a config property. Then this data will be available during the `initComponent` method  call in form 2, when the form is being created. During `initComponent`, simply make the fields visible/hidden based on the data that was passed in.